# Uber iOS SDK - how to add promotion codes Programmatically

Tags: ios, uber-api

`Uber iOS SDK`:

How to add promotion codes Programmatically using `Uber SDK`?

As of now only available using `Deep linking`, want to use in `Native SDK`

Comment: Please post your work

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you. So please, give it a try.

Comment: @Nattudurai How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to POST a promo code using the API. I believe you will have to use Deep Linking if you want to create a way to redirect users to add promotional codes in the Uber app.